# What's the movie where this guy finds that his world is simulated and tries to find those simulating it?

Tags: story-identification, virtual-worlds

He receives a letter telling him to go to a place that he would never think of going to--to just drive to a place he didn't know existed. When he does he sees that that part of the world (part of Texas?) hasn't been created yet--it's just a blueprint or something--just green lines of a simulation unfinished? He then goes on a hunt to find out the truth about the created world he lives in. He eventually meets someone in a tower in another world or simulation that has been controlling his simulation only to find out that everything is simulated?

Comment: This kind of reminds me of the book `The Parallel Man` by Richard Purtill. Obviously not a movie, but if you like that kind of theme but in a fantasy/future hybrid, you'll really enjoy this book.

Comment: It was the 13th Floor. Thanks though, I will check that book out.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The [13th Floor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139809/) (second take on Daniel Galouye's novel "[Simulacron-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacron-3)" after the german movie "[Welt am Draht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welt_am_Draht)"). However there is no time travel involved.

Comment: There was an element of time travel in that movie as the simulated worlds were always simulations of that world in the past. This isn't really time travel but it's easy to imagine that Cavion only vaguely remembered it.

Comment: I have to admit that I do not really know the movie - in the book the simulated world is not in the past (it mirrors the present day world for market research purposes).

Comment: In the film I believe the simulated reality is that of the 1930's

Comment: This was an example of a pre-Inception multi-stage simulated reality ("dream within a dream")

Comment: Yes it is The 13th Floor. I haven't seen that movie in over a decade (perhaps since I was 12 when it came out) but it has always been at the back of my mind. I've always been interested in parallel universes and other dimensions and about the nature of this world and universe. This world we are experiencing may be simulated as well. It's probably part of the reason why I am a philosopher today. Thank you very much for knowing what movie I was talking about and to everyone else who answered. I've been wondering about this movie for years but didn't know where to ask.

Comment: "I am a philosopher." "Oh... a bull@#%* artist." Sorry Cavion, not directed at you. It's one of my favorite quotes from a Mel Brooks movie, yet I seldom get a chance to use it.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a litle like the movie "The Truman Show" starring Jim Carry.  He was living in a completely simulated world, weather and all.

Comment: There are a couple of similarities between the description and The Truman Show, but Truman's world was an enclosed dome - not "-it's just a blueprint or something--just green lines of a simulation unfinished".

Comment: Thanks for answering but it was the 13th Floor. The Truman Show I will check out to refresh my memory.

Answer (score 2):

There a number of movies explorig this theme.

In addition to the given answers, exitenz by david croneburg is worth seeing. A lot of his films touch upon this questioning of reality.

Jacobs ladder, although not sci-fi is also good.

Comment: Are you saying that you think Existenz is the movie, or just that it's worth seeing?

Comment: The 13th Floor was the movie but thanks I will check out Exitenz and Jacob's Ladder as well.

Answer (score 2):

it's the 13th Floor. I just watched it. The time travel principal you remember is the fact that different world simulations are simulations of a different time. 1990s, 1937 and 2024

Comment: This answer does not add anything to the accepted answer.

Comment: @Monty129 The original question has a time-travel tag. I added explanation what time travel he remembered from the movie while the accepted answer says there is none.

Comment: Because there *isn't* time travel involved in the story.  The first comment on the accepted answer states the same thing as what your answer does.